# iPhone: How to create a tooltip like in Google Books app?

Tags: ios4

How can I code a tooltip just above the slider(like that shown in the shot) using Xcode ?

**Screenshot:** http://webtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/mzl.bboizaco.320x48075.jpg